# I want to add tkinter to this code and will do that but i don't know where to place the tkinter variables?, they will eventually be in the while true

Tags: python, tkinter

my code should be looking for search options and appending to a list that compares to the search, all im trying to figure out is how to get tkinter in the loop, because i dont know where to put things such as the if **name** == "main":
stuff

```
from tkinter import *
ideas = ["pooop", "pooop", "yaaah"]
describe = ["A software that provides poop images", "Fart noises", "kid on crack"]
window = Tk()
window.title("Exists?")






while True:

    function = input("Append or Search: ").lower().strip()

    if function == "append":
        appending = input("What would you like to append enter keywords/possible names..... ")
        ideas.append(appending)
        appending2 = input("Describe what you would like to append, please do not enter blank values as that will make "
                          "your software harder to find ")
        describe.append(appending2)
        print(ideas.index(str(appending)))
        print(describe.index(str(appending2)))
        searcher = input("What would you like to search for, enter keywords/possible names")
        if searcher in ideas:
            print(ideas)
            print("description: " + describe[ideas.index(searcher)])
            print(searcher in ideas)
            numberOfResults = str(ideas.count(searcher))
            print("0 results found")
        if searcher not in ideas:
            print(ideas)
            print(searcher in ideas)
            of = str(len(ideas))
            print("0 results found of " + of)

    if function == "search":
        searcher = input("What would you like to search for, enter keywords/possible names")
        if searcher in ideas:
            print(ideas)
            print("description: " + describe[ideas.index(searcher)])
            print(searcher in ideas)
            numberOfResults = str(ideas.count(searcher))
            print(numberOfResults + " results found")
        if searcher not in ideas:
            print(ideas)
            print(searcher in ideas)
            of = str(len(ideas))
            print("0 results found of " + of)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Uh, unless I'm missing something, why not just put the code in a loop?

Comment: @LayneBernardo the reason putting the code in a loop isn't the best option is because the appended list restarts - sorry, it's because I had put the starting variables inside the loop, it is fine now thank you!

Comment: It only 'restarts' if you include the initialization code in the loop. See 'Алексей Р's answer, that's what I was getting at.

Comment: yep got it, sorry I was thinking a bit weird, because when i ha put it in a while true loop before it didn't work, but its fine now thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put the code in an infinite loop and exit when a word other than `append` or `search` is entered

```
ideas = ["pooop", "pooop", "yaaah"]
describe = ["A software that provides poop images", "Fart noises", "kid on crack"]

while True:  # infinity loop
    function = input("Append or Search: ").lower().strip()

    if function == "append":
        pass  # ... you code instead

    elif function == "search":
        pass  # ... you code instead

    else:  # other input
        print("That's all!")
        break  # exit loop
```